# C: fgets() and command line input

Tags: c, fgets, strtok

I'm trying to write a program that handles processes.
The user will be prompted..

```
shell: start emacs file.c
Process 346 has started.
```

I'm having a few issues with fgets, since I don't know what to put as my third argument (I want it to take in from the command line/argv) with

**fgets(buffer, 4096,** How can I do a file pointer if I'm not doing a file, **just argv?)**

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)   
{
 while(1) {
    printf("shell: ");   
int status, pid;
int i=0;
char buffer[4097];
    fgets(buffer, 4096, ???? ) //I want it to take in from argv. Do I need to declare 4096?

if(strcmp(argv[1],"start") == 0 )
    { printf("myshell: process has started \n");
           while (str = strtok(buffer," ") = NULL)  //??? What do I declare str as?
            argv[i] = str;    
            i = i+1;
            }      

            if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {  //Child process fork
            perror("fork");       
            exit(1);
            }
            if (pid == 0) {  //Child executes code
            execvp(argv[0], argv );
            perror(argv[1]);    //argv1? 
            exit(1);
             }
    }
```

Does this make sense fort the desired behavior explained above? I'm not entirely sure of the location of my while loop that has strtok, didn't know if that maybe has to be outside of the if-statement.

Also, is it correct for my strtok function to be called as strtok(buffer, " ")? Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like someone needs to read some man pages...

Comment: `char buffer[4097]; fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, ...`

Comment: To clarify, I did see in the man pages that the third argument is "FILE * restrict stream" but I didn't know what to exactly since I don't take any input for a file and typically it's a pointer to a file.

Comment: @user3295684 you  stated that start emacs file.c so your third argument is file.c. So think you first open that file and pass the FILE pointer of that file in third argument of fgets function.

Comment: @JKB Got it, so like FILE *src = fopen(argv[3],"r");
        fgets(buffer, MAX, src); Thank you!

Comment: @user3295674 yes you are right...any way welcome friend

Answer (score 0):

```
 I don't know what to put as my third argument ??
```

From the man page, 

`char *fgets(char * restrict s, int n, FILE * restrict stream);`

So third argument is `FILE` pointer. Since `argv` is pointer to string, you can't use in `fgets()` as mentioned.

you can directly use or copy to some local buffer using `strcpy()` family of functions.

Comment: So I can potentially do something like fgets(buffer, 4096, argv)?

Comment: @user3295674 No, not argv but from argv you get file name.so first open file and pass the  file pointe of it.

Answer (score 0):

You are going wrong entirely my friend
when you will start program through terminal (./your_program argv1 argv2 ... argvN) argv is passed by system to the main function, but after starting the program nothing will going store in argv i.e.

./your_program argv1 argv2    //here you can collect string input from system
shell: start emac file.c   //this will not stored into argv

to take value those value you can something do like that
   fgets(buffer, 4096,stdin)  // from console into your buffer not in argv

and after that you can use string tokeniser function to take each value from buffer
I do not know exact syntax or program for string tokeniser but this link will help you
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/